# Game involving runner character and trees/shrubs that power up

Tags: windows, android, macos, game

I'm looking for a game where a person that can walk, trot, run, or walk with different gaits at different speeds, can run on a path, with different obstacles.

The game is 2D.

The runner passes by trees, which are found at various locations, across the path.

The runner smells oxygen which is inhaled and appears as some sort of round water droplets from the tree, as if from under an armpit.

This, allows the runner to run faster, but as the runner gets far from the trees, they lose oxygen, and run or walk slower

The runner may have to walk back to gain oxygen from a tree.

There could be walls, ponds, frogs, foxlets, whales, and other small shrubs (also, emitting a scent, which could have, according to the shrub, or flower, various power up effects, on, the person, character).

Where can I find such a plant/tree game, or similar?

A 3D version, where the user could go into paths on a plane with hilly slopes, would also be nice.

Thanks.

Thank you for your contributions.

I think, the game, could be quite nice.